# Python - loop through lists with recursion

Tags: python, list, loops, recursion

I have a question regarding recursion. I want a function that takes one specific letter from my_input as an input and
creates the list called my_output. The function loops through the my_input-list and its sublists and adds every list
that starts with one of the letters in every sublist to my_output.

```
my_input = [
    ["A", "B", "C"],
    ["D", "E", "F"],
    ["B", "G", "H"],
    ["H", "I", "J"],
]

my_output = [
    ["A", "B", "C"],
    ["B", "G", "H"],
    ["H", "I", "J"],
]
```

For instance: The starting letter is "A". The function looks for the sublist that starts with "A" and adds
it to my_output. Than it takes "B" (the second letter in this sublist) and looks if a sublist exists, that
starts with "B" which is true and adds this one as well to my_output. It does the same with "C" (but here is
no sublist that starts with "C"). Now it does the same with the second list in my_output and checks the
letters "G" and "H" (no result for "G" but one for "H" -> add the sublist that starts with "H" to my_output.
It finally checks the letters "I" and "J" but does not find any result. The function returns my_output.

By that problem I expected to learn how to create recursive functions (at least I hope this is the right/best
way to solve this problem), but I do not get it.

Thanks in advance.

By the way: This works but i assume it is not nice, there must be a better way?

```
def get_my_output(letter):
    checked_letters = []
    my_output = []
    for i in my_input:
        if i[0] == letter:
            checked_letters.append(i[0])
            my_output.append(i)
    for j in my_output:
        for k in j:
            if k not in checked_letters:
                for l in my_input:
                    if l[0] == k:
                        if l not in my_output:
                            my_output.append(l)
            else:
                continue
    return my_output
```

Answer (score 0):

### Recursion

> By that problem I expected to learn how to create recursive functions (at least I hope this is the right/best way to solve this problem), but I do not get it.

In recursion, you're always 'going over' some data structure, usually adding the output of the deeper recursion layer to the output of the caller. Oftentimes, this results in a function, that calls itself *at the end* (*tail recursion*).

The important part is, that you always need some kind of halting condition (the *recursion anchor*), which prevents infinitely calling your function again and again.

### Solution

For demonstration purposes, I wrote this code very verbose and added extensive comments to it. Since you did not specify a recursion anchor, I'm removing all lists from the input that were already added to the output:

```
from typing import List

def recurse_list(input_list: List[List[str]], starting_letter: str) -> List[List[str]]:
    result = []
    # get lists starting with desired letter
    current_lists = [l for l in input_list if l[0] == starting_letter]
    result.extend(current_lists)
    for current_list in current_lists:
        # recursively append lists starting with the latter letters in the current list
        for letter in current_list[1:]:
            # remove all lists from ``input_list`` that are already added to the result
            # this acts as a recursion anchor to stop execution at some point
            rest = [l for l in input_list if l not in result]
            result.extend(recurse_list(rest, letter))
    return result

my_output = recurse_list(my_input, "A")
print(my_output)
```

Result:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['B', 'G', 'H'], ['H', 'I', 'J']]
```

---

### Your solution

> By the way: This works but i assume it is not nice, there must be a
> better way?
>
> ```
> def get_my_output(letter):
>     checked_letters = []
>     my_output = []
>     for i in my_input:
>         if i[0] == letter:
>             checked_letters.append(i[0])
>             my_output.append(i)
>     for j in my_output:
>         for k in j:
>             if k not in checked_letters:
>                 for l in my_input:
>                     if l[0] == k:
>                         if l not in my_output:
>                             my_output.append(l)
>             else:
>                 continue
>     return my_output
> ```

Here, `if k not in checked_letters` acts as recursion anchor. In overall, you used the correct structure. However, you do not call `get_my_output()`, thus this is an iterative instead of a recursive solution.

Besides, you can minimize code lines and cognitive load by using python's list comprehensions (`[x for x in my_list if <condition>]`) instead of the nested for loops and if conditions. And you don't need the `else: continue` case, which just does nothing.

Additionally, your approach uses a second aggregator variable (`checked_letters`), which you would have to provide to recursive calls, thus introducing a parameter, that the function should not have. You could, however, still add this using a default argument, so the first call would work without it, e.g., `def get_my_output(letter, checked_letters=())` - I'd still suggest adding my_input as a parameter, too, to make the function reusable for other inputs. Here, the default argument `()` is a tuple, because this is immutable and, thus, stays empty if not explicitly set. A mutable default argument in Python such as a list `[]` would keep the value from the last call, thus polluting future calls and possibly leaking into unrelated execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list comprehension` to accommodate the recursion. Your recursive function will take the input letter and the input list 'my_input` to start processing.

You will need to keep an `array` to track down whether you have `visited` the recursive function with that `input_letter`. For the unvisited letter we can find out the list of rows valid from `my_input` and then extend our local output array.
Then each letter in the fetched letter list of each of the list of letter lists, we will call the recursive function to get the result.

The base condition will be return empty array if no valid list of letter is found from the `my_input`

The aforementioned whole program is given below:

```
my_input = [
    ["A", "B", "C"],
    ["D", "E", "F"],
    ["B", "G", "H"],
    ["H", "I", "J"],
]

visited = []

def list_with_recursion(letter_input, input_matrix):
    output = []
    if letter_input not in visited:
        visited.append(letter_input)
    else:
        return output

    input_letter_list = [x for x in input_matrix if x[0] == letter_input]
    if len(input_letter_list) == 0:
        return output
    output.extend(input_letter_list)

    func = lambda letter: list_with_recursion(letter, input_matrix)
    res = [func(x) for letter_list in input_letter_list for x in letter_list]
    output.extend(ele_list for lst in res for ele_list in lst if lst != [])
    return output


my_output = list_with_recursion('A', my_input)
print(my_output)
```

which gives:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['B', 'G', 'H'], ['H', 'I', 'J']]
```

Answer (score 0):

**generators**

This is a good use case for generators. We can write `traverse` to accept a `graph` and a `query`, such as `my_input` and `"A"` in your question. We use an additional parameter, `visited`, to keep track of nodes in the graph that have already been visited -

```py
def traverse(graph, query, visited = {}):
  if query in visited: return
  for nodes in graph:
    if nodes[0] == query:
      yield nodes
      for node in nodes:
        yield from traverse(graph, node, { *visited, query })
```

```py
my_input = [
    ["A", "B", "C"],
    ["D", "E", "F"],
    ["B", "G", "H"],
    ["H", "I", "J"],
]

print(list(traverse(my_input, "A")))
```

```py
[
  ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  ['B', 'G', 'H'],
  ['H', 'I', 'J']
]
```

Above we used `list(...)` to capture the generator output into a list, `[...]`. Sometimes you might wish to skip this step and perform the effect directly on each element. Generators are iterable, meaning we can step thru one using `for` or comprehensions -

```py
for x in traverse(my_input, "A"):
  print(x)
```

```py
['A', 'B', 'C']
['B', 'G', 'H']
['H', 'I', 'J']
```

We see slightly different output when we start with `query = "B"` -

```py
for x in traverse(my_input, "B"):
  print(x)
```

```py
['B', 'G', 'H']
['H', 'I', 'J']
```

We only see one line for `query = "D"`

```py
for x in traverse(my_input, "D"):
  print(x)
```

```py
['D', 'E', 'F']
```

And for `query = "Z"`, we get an empty output -

```py
print(list(traverse(my_input, "Z")))
```

```py
[]
```

**alternative implementation**

We can implement `traverse` in a variety of ways. Instead of using `visited` like we did above, we could make the assumption that the head of sublist is unique, and not repeated later in the graph -

```py
def traverse(graph, query):
  for nodes in graph:
    if nodes[0] == query:
      yield nodes
      for node in nodes[1:]:
        yield from traverse(graph, node)
```

Destructuring of `nodes` into `first` and `*rest` is another option -

```py
def traverse(graph, query):
  for nodes in graph:
    [first, *rest] = nodes
    if first == query:
      yield nodes
      for node in rest:
        yield from traverse(graph, node)
```

A drawback of these simpler alternatives is that sublists like `["A", "B", "C", "A"]` where "A" is repeated multiple times in a single sublist, or having `"A"` appear in multiple sublists such as `[["A","B","C"],["C","A","F"],...]` would cause a stack overflow. The first implementation in this post does not suffer from this problem.